# 了 in 我在这里两个星期了 / "I've been here for two weeks"

Tags: translation, particles

What is the precise function of 了 in the sentence

```
我在这里两个星期了 / "I've been here for two weeks"
```

?

Is it a marker of completed action? Is it saying "already"? What does the sentence mean if 了 were omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 我在这里两个星期了

了 here denotes a completion. It could be rendered with the perfect tense in English. *Staying here for two weeks is completed*, namely *I have been here for two weeks(already)*.

Answer (score 0):

I think this 了 is just for emphasis, or to show you are done speaking.